# Asp dot net Web method is not getting called from select2 ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get remote data from select2 js using webmethod in c# code however with no luck.I want to get control to my webmethod which isn't happening now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (jQuery.fn.select2) {
        $('#ctl00_Accounts').select2({
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Pages/Common/Home.aspx/GetSearch',
                datatype: "json",
                data: function(params) {
                    debugger;
                    return JSON.stringify({
                        prefixText: params.term // search term
                    });
                },
                processResults: function(data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.items
                    };
                },
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3
        });
    }
});
```

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<CustomerInfo> GetSearch(string prefixText)
{
    int countCustomers = 50

    List<CustomerInfo> dataOutput = Fleetcor.GFN.Reflex.UI.Security.ReflexMembership.AvailableCustomers((int)Fleetcor.GFN.Reflex.UI.Security.ReflexMembership.CurrentUser.Account.UserID, false);

    List<CustomerInfo> output = dataOutput.FindAll(item => item.CustomerName.Contains(prefixText));
    if (output.Count > countCustomers)
    {
        output = output.GetRange(0, countCustomers);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? What are the debug outputs?

Comment: Luck won't help. Find error in dev tool console and by debugging web method

Comment: There is no error shown in console and I can debug webmethod only when control comes there. I've put debugger on web method and I'm expecting it to come there.

Answer (score 0):

Check url and data attributes inside ajax ,Try i this way may be this helps.

```js
function Something() {  
    var userid = $("#reguser").val();  
    jQuery.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "YourPage.aspx/yourMethodName",  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        data: "{'userID':'" + userid + "'}",  
        
        success: function (msg) {  
            alert("success");
                }  
                else {  
                }  
            });  
        },  
        error: function (d) {  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Comment: I confirmed URL in fiddler and it is redirecting to right URL and passing correct json. Also, It is going into success method and returning "success". That's where the problem is, I'm not able to figure out the problem as no error are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomerInfo` class must contain the below two property  because `select2` jquery plugin will accept only these property names.and map the results to `CustomerInfo` class and return in `json` format.

```
public class CustomerInfo 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    //others prop
}
```

Source https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Comment: thanks for your reponse. Returning a json is next step where I'm stuck. Firstly, my control should reach to Webmethod which isn't happening.